# Yii - using afterDelete() to update data in another table

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii afterdelete() to update the related data which is deleted in another table. Here is my code in the controller:

**Controller Action**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}
```

**Model function**

```
  protected function afterDelete()
   {
        parent::afterDelete();
        $show_model = new Show();
        $show_model = Show::model()->findAll('tbl_season_id='.$this->id);
        $show_model->updateAll('tbl_season_id = NULL, on_season=0');

   }
```

Comment: What's the problem with it? Are you getting an error? A quick read flags up a few things you could change, but it looks like it should be working.

Comment: No, I don't get any error. First I understood that I made a mistake, and in shouldn't be inside the controller... But still it doesn't work, I tried to use var dump to see if the function is executing after delete but I see no results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Gregor said, a good use of active record relations would make the job much easier.
So, in **Show** model you would have something like:

```
     public function relations()
     {
        return array(
            'season' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Season', 'tbl_season_id'),
        );
     }
```

While in **Season** model you would have something like:

```
     public function relations()
     {
        return array(
            'shows' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Show', 'tbl_show_id'),
        );
     }
```

Having relations defined, will give you the ability to do this:

```
     public function afterDelete()
     {
         parent::afterDelete();
         $season_shows = Season::model()->findByID($id)->shows; //using the shows relation
         foreach($season_shows as $season_show) do
         {
            $season_show->setAttributes('tbl_season_id => NULL, on_season => 0');
            $season_show->save();
         }

     }
```

Hummm, but if you noticed that second line in the `afterDelete` which calls `findByID($id)` but we are inside the `afterDelete` and the record is actually dead (deleted)!!

To fix this you can grab the `id` just before the model is deleted using a `variable` & a`beforeDelete`

```
    //at the begining of your model class
    $private = $cached_season_id;
    ...
    //then somewhere at the end
    ... 
    public function beforeDelete()
     {
          $this->cached_tbl_season_id = $this->id;
          return parent::beforeDelete();
     }
```

Now if you change the `id` in the `afterDelete` to `$this->cached_season_id` .. it should work.

Well, this solution is based on this [yii-fourm-topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17589-best-way-to-delete-child-record-in-yii/) and i am not quite sure if it's going to work as it is!! So, give it a try & let us know what happens?

Comment: Working on a legacy Yii 1.1 project at the moment.

When deleting an AR model, or `CActiveRecord` more precisely, the properties of the instance are not purged upon `delete()` so there's no need to cache the `id` of the instance being deleted, just use `$this->id` in `afterDelete()`, or one could iterate the relation directly i.e. `foreach (this->shows as $show)`

Answer (score 1):

That looks an awful lot like a HAS_MANY relationship from Season to Show, so you might want to use relations in the future to get related records. There is a pretty good documentation for that in the yii-guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

It also seems to me, that you have a jQuery-background. You are calling updateAll on an array(which is returned by the findAll-function).
A proper updateAll-call might look like this:

```
Show::model()->updateAll(array("tbl_season_id"=>null, "on_season"=>0), "tbl_season_id = $this->id")
```

This would probably be even better with some kind of constraint but since that is imo a matter of taste, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I tried the correct updateALL() but still not working. I have defined the HAS_MANY relationship. but I couldn't figure out how I can use it to update my tables.

Comment: You could for example iterate through $this->relationName in your afterDelete. It might look like this:
    foreach ($this->Shows as $show) {
    $show->attribute = 123;
    $show->save();
}

Though, if your are updating a lot of Shows, updateAll would be the way to go since it uses queries instead of AR.